# Using findViewById in Activity's onCreate not behaving as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, oncreate

I'm attempting to use a 'RangeSeekBar' (https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/). This has to be done in the code rather than the XML, so I've plugged the sample code into my activity's onCreate method as instructed.

My code falls apart at the `findViewById` method outlined below. Using the sample code, I get the following two outcomes:

1. If I try to get the LinearLayout directly by referring to its ID, I get a null pointer exception. I expect this to provide the LinearLayout, I don't understand why this is null.
2. If I refer to `R.id.container`, I can insert the RangeSeekBar but it overlaps the first field. Note that if I try to cast the container to a LinearLayout instead of ViewGroup, I get an error that indicates that the container is a FrameLayout, which tells me the container isn't the LinearLayout that I want it to be.

My question is this, **How do I insert the RangeSeekBar into the fragment ViewGroup so that it adheres to the LinearLayout?** Or, **How do I retrieve my fragment LinearLayout from the activity onCreate and avoid a null pointer exception?**

**Update**: I had previously listed the fragment xml rather than the activity xml. I've updated the question with both XML below.

Here's my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_seeds);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    // I replaced the sample code's "context" with getBaseContext() should this be something else??
    //RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(20, 75, context); //CODE SAMPLE 
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 40, getBaseContext()); //MY VERSION

    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            // handle changed range values
            Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
        }
    });

    // add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout
    //ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(<your-layout-id>); //SAMPLE CODE
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container); //MY CODE THAT SORT OF WORKS
    layout.addView(seekBar); // This inserts the RangeSeekBar overlapping the Name field

    //ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_manage); //MY CODE THAT RETURNS A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION AT RUNTIME
    //layout.addView(seekBar); // This causes the null pointer exception because the line above returns null.
}
```

Here's my fragment XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_manage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/test_edit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/test_edit_name" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/test_edit_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/test_edit_type" />

    <!-- I want the custom RangeSeekBar added here. Must be done via java code, not possible through XML -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_button_save"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my activity_manage_seeds xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mypackage.myapp.ManageSeedsActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: You can keep an empty linear layout in between the layouts, and inflate rangebar there programatically.

Comment: But what is `R.id.container`?? You don't have any view with this id in Your xml?

Comment: The question has been updated to include the activity xml, @Gustek, which I hand overlooked because I was working with the fragment file. I hadn't understood the the difference between the activity vs fragment xml which I do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a tidier solution to this is to add a FrameLayout into your existing LinearLayout, and add the RangeSeekBar into the FrameLayout. See below:

```
<!-- Activity Layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/layout_manage"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/test_edit_name"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/test_edit_type"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- This is the container for the RangeSeekBar -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/range_seek_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your onCreate() method may look as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(20, 75, context);

    ViewGroup rangeBarContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.range_seek_bar_container);
    rangeBarContainer.addView(rangeSeekBar);
}
```

This makes it much easier to edit the RangeSeekBar's layout attributes

**Update**

Upon reading your new code, I noticed you are attempting to edit the layout of one of your Fragments from your `Activity` code. You shouldn't do this. Work inside `PlaceholderFragment`.

Your onCreateView() method inside `PlaceholderFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);

    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(20, 75, context);

    ViewGroup rangeBarContainer = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.range_seek_bar_container);
    rangeBarContainer.addView(rangeSeekBar);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that approach never occurred to me, thanks for suggesting it. I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification after my update. This has helped me understand the android activities and fragments a bit more clearly.

Comment: No worries, the Android API guides offer a good amount of info on how Activities and Fragments interact with each other

[Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)
-
[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1):

1) NullPointerExcption occus when you try to asscess a View which does not resides in your layout file (activity_manage_seeds).

Please make sure that your Viewgroup layout_manage is there in activity_manage_seeds.xml file.

2) Regarding your seekbar position you need to add layout parameters to set its proper location, provided you viewGroup R.id.container resides in activity_manage_seeds.xml which is not there in your xml file shown above.

Comment: 1) Ah, I see. Then I guess my question actually is: how do I access the LinearLayout from my fragment XML, which is where my other View objects are defined. I'll update the question to reflect this detail (I hadn't understood that before, thanks). 2) container is in the activity_manage_seeds.xml, whereas I had posted the fragment XML file instead. I'll update the question with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You got the linear layout id wrong in the code try changing it to layout_manage instead of container.

Comment: Unfortunately, as my comment at the end of the code sample states, this yields a null pointer exception at runtime. layout_manage just doesn't work.

Comment: A quick update: I provided my fragment xml (where layout_manage resides) rather than my activity xml. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a View that is not on your xml thats why it returns nullpointer..

change the layout of this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_seeds);
```

to the layout where the id `R.id.container` resides

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand. My understanding is that the activity (ManageSeedsActivity) is activated and then this onCreate method is called from that file, so the setContentView should be polnting to that activity because its the onCreate for that activity. Is this correct? R.id.container came from the activities XML file (which I've updated in the question). What I want is the LinearLayout in my fragment xml file. So my question is now: how to retrieve the fragment LinearLayout from the Activity onCreate?